# Iframe comes back blank in HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

My iframe comes back blank.

```
<iframe src="http://www.victradeshall.com/mcauley/76123Ilj71jh/334254jdlIa91iI194L71l872lI1/index.html"/>
```

I am using Firefox 29.0 and Chrome 35.0. Both of the browser are showing the same result. What is the problem?

Comment: Please check response headers in developer tools for the embedded page when you don't have it in an iframe (i.e. it works) it for things like `Access-Control-Allow-Origins` and `X-Frame-Options`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set this up in JSFiddle to check it was working, which it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/0r11e1jg/

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.victradeshall.com/mcauley/76123Ilj71jh/334254jdlIa91iI194L71l872lI1/index.html"></iframe>
```

The only difference between your code and mine is that I've added in width and height.

If it's not working then I'd think it is probably a wordpress related issue, and I'd recommend that you take a look at this thread:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-iframe-in-wordpress

It could be that you need to install a plugin - like this one which will allow you to put wordpress in place:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-iframe/

This thread gives you some other options on the various plugin options:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-iframe-in-wordpress

Hope that helps!